# how to react in a custom emoji

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to react with a personalized emoji, but I can't

```
      msg.react('<:info:753347236842438707>').then(r => { //custom emoji
      msg.react('').then(r => { //emoji working


error: DiscordAPIError: Invalid From Body
emoji_id: Value: "753347236842438707" is not snowflake.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to define the emoji:

```js
const info = client.emojis.cache.get('753347236842438707');
```

Next, reacting to the message:

```js
const info = client.emojis.cache.get('753347236842438707');
message.channel.send('content').then(msg => {
    await msg.react(info);
    await msg.react('');
}
```